# hover mouse over separate div and re-open another faded out div

Tags: jquery, html, hover, mouse

I want to be able to hover my mouse over my logo on the home screen to bring back the faded out text and image in the div underneath. (The text and image fade out after 9 seconds of the page opening unless interrupted by the mouse).

you can see the home page here www.dgimages.co.nz

My JS code for the fading etc is below but is probably not needed for what i want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var fade = setTimeout(function(){
    $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").remove();
    });
}, 9000);

    $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").mouseout(function(e) {
    fade = setTimeout(function(){
        $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").remove();
        });
    }, 9000);
});

    $("div.left-col-wrap-outer").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(fade);
    });

});
```

my logo is in a div class="logo"
How do i do this?

Comment: Why are you calling `.remove()` on the element after it fades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fading a `div` in and out on hover can be done entirely with CSS. The only thing you really need your jQuery for is doing your initial delayed fade-out on page load.

The trick is actually fairly simple. An outer container contains both your logo and the content you would like to fade. The container to be faded is faded in and out using CSS transitions when the user hovers on and stops hovering on *the outer container*. Thus, instead of using something like `#logo:hover`, you end up using something more like `#outer:hover #fade`.

[Here's a fiddle demonstrating the CSS hover fade effect](http://jsfiddle.net/uBu2e/3/).

[More information about CSS transitions can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions).

The HTML:

```
<div id="outer">

    <img /> <!-- Your logo -->

    <div id="fade">
        <img /> <!-- Any images you want in the faded out menu -->
        <h3>I like bells.</h3>
    </div>

</div>​
```

And the CSS:

```
#outer {
    width:120px;
}

#fade {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition-property:opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    -moz-transition-property:opacity;
    -moz-transition-duration:1s;
    -ms-transition-property:opacity;
    -ms-transition-duration:1s;
    -o-transition-property:opacity;
    -o-transition-duration:1s;
}

#outer:hover #fade {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition-property:opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    -moz-transition-property:opacity;
    -moz-transition-duration:1s;
    -ms-transition-property:opacity;
    -ms-transition-duration:1s;
    -o-transition-property:opacity;
    -o-transition-duration:1s;
}
```

Comment: Nice to see how it is done with CSS, but I think I prefer four lines of jQuery to twenty lines of CSS. (Especially when jQuery is needed anyway to do it on page load.)

Comment: lol Yeah. It probably would be overkill to use both solutions.